# Embed 1bpp image in PDF using python and reportlab

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm trying to embed a 1bpp image in PDF using python and reportlab.

The following code embeds the image, but reportlab seems to be converting to 8-bit first:

```
import subprocess
from PIL import Image
import reportlab.pdfgen.canvas

filename = "test.pbm"
subprocess.run(["convert", "magick:netscape", "test.pbm"], check=True)
print(subprocess.check_output(["identify","test.pbm"], text=True))

image = Image.open(filename)

c = reportlab.pdfgen.canvas.Canvas("test.pdf", pagesize=image.size) 
c.drawImage(filename, 0, 0)

c.showPage()
c.save()

subprocess.run(["pdfimages","test.pdf","x"], check=True)
print(subprocess.check_output(["identify","x-000.p*m"], text=True))
```

Of course, the 8-bit image is significantly larger than the 1-bit one.

According to the [reportlab docs](https://docs.reportlab.com/reportlab/userguide/ch2_graphics/), `drawImage()` also accepts a PIL object instead of a filename. However, if I replace the call with this:

```
c.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
```

I get the error message:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not PpmImageFile
```

I'd appreciate any insight.